# Laravel , suddenly query error

Tags: laravel, model, settings, share

I used a code in my Basecontroller to share data with all the views ( for footer and header informations ) , it worked great but suddenly i was working on something totally different and i've got an error : No query results for model [Variable]

Can't understand why i didn't even modify my BaseController.

Here is my Base Controller :

```
 public function __construct(){
        $this->getVariable('horaire');
        $this->getVariable('facebook');
        $this->getVariable('contact');
        $this->getVariable('twitter');
        $main_slider = MainSlider::all();
        View::share('main_slider',$main_slider);
    }
 public function getVariable($setting)
    {
        $variables[$setting] = Variable::where('name', $setting)->FirstOrFail();
        $values[$setting] = $variables[$setting]->value;
        View::share($setting, $values[$setting]);
    }
```

And what I was working on

```
Class VariablesController extends BaseController {

    public function settings(){
        $settings['about'] = Variable::where('name','about')->FirstOrFail();
        $settings['contact'] = Variable::where('name','contact')->FirstOrFail();
        $settings['horaire'] = Variable::where('name','horaire')->FirstOrFail();
        $settings['legals'] = Variable::where('name','legals')->FirstOrFail();
        $settings['facebook'] = Variable::where('name','facebook')->FirstOrFail();
        $settings['twitter'] = Variable::where('name','twitter')->FirstOrFail();
        $settings['contact_email'] = Variable::where('name','contact_email')->FirstOrFail();
        return View::make('admin.settings',compact('settings'));

    }

    public function update(){
        $inputs['facebook'] = e(Input::get('facebook'));
        $inputs['twitter'] = e(Input::get('twitter'));
        $inputs['contact_email'] = e(Input::get('contact_email'));
        $inputs['legals'] = e(Input::get('legals'));
        $inputs['horaire'] = e(Input::get('horaire'));
        $inputs['contact'] = e(Input::get('contact'));
        $inputs['about'] = e(Input::get('about'));
        foreach($inputs as $name => $input){
            echo "$name => $input";
        }
    }
```

And my Variable model :

```
<?php

class Variable extends \Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = ['id','created_at','protected_at'];

    protected $table = 'variables';
}
```

Thank you for your helps

Comment: What error you have?

Comment: Did you change the data in your db in the meantime so one of the queries yields an empty result?

Comment: Error : " No query results for model [Variable]. "

Comment: Yes , this is the first thing I checked , all the data are filled in the db , no empty field